# Finite dimensional irreducible projective representations of $SO^+(1,3)$

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

### **Conventions:**

Take the Minkowski metric tensor to have signature $(+, -, -, -)$. Use Hermitian (instead of skew-symmetric) generators of rotations $J_i$ and anti-Hermitian (instead of symmetric) generators of boosts $K_i$.

### **Background:**

The task is to find finite dimensional projective representations of the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3)$. By a technical chain of theorems, this is equivalent to finding Lie algebra representations of the Lorentz algebra $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. The Lorentz algebra is given by  3+3 Hermitian/Antihermitian generators $\{J_i, K_i\}$ that obey the commutation relations
$$[J_i, J_j] = i\epsilon^{ijk}J_k, \ \ [J_i, K_j] = i\epsilon^{ijk}K_k, \ \ [K_i, K_j] = -i\epsilon^{ijk}J_k.$$

In order to facilitate this process, it is convenient to complexify the Lorentz algebra to its complexification $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\mathbb{C}$. This allows us to define new generators with commutation relations
$$[A_i, A_j] = i\epsilon^{ijk}A_k, \ \ [A_i, B_j] = 0, \ \ [B_i, B_j] = i\epsilon^{ijk}B_k.$$
This gives us the exceptional isomorphism
$$\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C},L} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}, R} \tag{1}$$
where we have distinguished the two summands of $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$, we also have that
$$\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\mathbb{C} \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})_L \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})_R. \tag{2}$$
By an additional technical theorem, we obtain the fact that the finite dimensional irreducible representations of a direct sum of Lie algebras are precisely the single tensor products of irreducible representations of the summands.

Since we know well the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$, we are in business. Wikipedia gives the real restriction of the irreducible representations of the right hand side of $(1)$ as
$$\pi_{m,n}(X,Y) = (\pi_m \otimes \pi_n)(X,Y), \quad X \in \mathfrak{su}(2), \ Y \in \mathfrak{su}(2). \tag{3}$$

### **Question:**

Why do we distinguish the two summands and how do we formally distinguish the two summands?

Comment: Why shouldn't you distinguish them? They are different blocks of the direct-sum-of-generators matrix. Beyond hyper-general/abstract bloviation, have you worked out a simple example?

Comment: Yes, I have. @CosmasZachos

Comment: What in my post is abstract bloviation? @CosmasZachos

Comment: It's not clear to me what this question is asking: When you look at $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$, you don't ask "why do we distinguish the two summands?", you just write elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as tuples of elements $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, and $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are clearly different elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$. What's different in this case from the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Pardon my instinctive recoil from mathematese. I, and I assume readers not repaying you with the same abstractions in an answer, would like to know what in a simple matrix example would mean to not distinguish the two summands...

Comment: Small mistake: the boost generators cannot be hermitian.

Comment: I’m having a hard time understanding the question. Are asking whether the direct sum decomposition is basis independent (or canonical in some sense)? Or are you asking how to construct irreps knowing this decomposition?

Comment: @LPZ The boosts are antihermitean, but multiplied by an *i* they turn hermitean for the complexification of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group).

Comment: I think LPZ is right. I mean to use the physics convention in which the $J_i$ are Hermitian and the $K_i$ are anti-Hermitian. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What I do not understand is why can we not replace $\mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}_L} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}_R}$ with $\mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}_L} \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}_L}$. Which is analogous to you saying that $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ is spanned by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. In other words, it seems like the distinguishment has something to do with our initial definitions of generators $A_i$ and $B_i$, a choice which I think should not affect the proceeding analysis.

Comment: @LPZ Perhaps my comment to ACM also answers your comment.

Comment: Formally, the two *su(2)* algebras are the same, but they correspond to different combinations in representation matrices, cf., e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas). A change of basis would segregate them to different blocks.

Comment: Note your finite-dimensional irreps are necessarily non-unitary, as detailed in Wu-Ki Tung's clear book, Group theory in Physics, Sec 10.3.1 & 10.3.2. The L  vs R distinction simply locates the corresponding block matrices in your matrix irrep construction.  But, caveat, both this book and WP (Weinberg's) use the east-coast metric, not the west-coast you chose.